# Create python class sub-class / nested attributes dynamically

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance

I'd like the define nested attributes in a class such as:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def ___init__(self, a, b, c):
         self.a = a
         self.lowerlevel.b = b
         self.lowerlevel.evenlower.c = c
```

But when I try to initialise the class I get the error:

```
MyClass object has no attribute lowerlevel.
```

How can I fix this please?

Comment: What should `self.lowerlevel` return?

Comment: It should return whatever I set as b when I make the class. e.g.:
foo = MyClass('astring','bstring','cstring')
and then
foo.lowerlevel.b should return 'bstring'

Comment: I mean `self.lowerlevel`, not `self.lowerlevel.b`.

Comment: Could it be because there's 3 underscores before init instead of two ?

Comment: Well, the error message is pretty clear, you never assigned `lowerlevel`, so you can't access an attribute (`b` or `c`) of something that wasn't defined (`lowerlevel`).

Comment: How can I then define lowerlevel please, so that I can then add variables as attributes?

Comment: @IanRoberts see the answer on the duplicate